# How to link "aws_apigatewayv2_route" with "aws_apigatewayv2_integration"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I am creating a terraform script for Amazon API Gateway Version 2 using terraform, using HTTP protocol type. I am not able to figure out how to link the gateway route with the integration. I have tried using the "target" attribute in "aws_apigatewayv2_route" but its not working. Below is the code I have written for it.

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "mrw-api" {
  name          = "mrw-http-api"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_vpc_link" "mrw-link" {
  name               = "mrw-link"
  security_group_ids = [data.aws_security_group.mrw-sg.id]
  subnet_ids         = [data.aws_subnet.mrw-subnet.id, data.aws_subnet.mrw-subnet2.id]

}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "healthcheck" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.mrw-api.id
  route_key = "GET /"
  target    = aws_apigatewayv2_integration.mrw-int-get.id
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "mrw-int-get" {
  api_id             = aws_apigatewayv2_api.mrw-api.id
  integration_type   = "HTTP_PROXY"
  connection_type    = "VPC_LINK"
  connection_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_vpc_link.mrw-link.id
  integration_uri    = aws_lb_listener.mrw-lb-listener.arn
  integration_method = "GET"
  tls_config {
    server_name_to_verify = var.tls_server_name
  }
}
```

Can anyone help on how to link the route with the integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform's documentation for this isn't very clear. The format for `target` is `integrations/integration-id`. In your case, use `"integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.mrw-int-get.id}"`